# Bootstrap 3, how to make a col on two rows with changed order in display screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I'm designing a dashboard, and I want it to be in that way when in mobile screen : [image]

But when in a large screen, I want the "Results" div to be smaller and in the right corner.
So far I almost managed to do what I want, but I got a little problem :
[image]

There is a gap between "Results" and "Stats"&"Perf". And I would like the "Winner" column to be full heigth, to finish in the same level as "Perf" for exemple.

Here is the code I got so far :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-push-4">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Results</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-lg-pull-8">
        <h2>Winner</h2>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4">
        <h2>Stats</h2>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4">
        <h2>Perf</h2>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
</div>
```

I tried too to make two rows, one with "Winner" and another with the rest, but wasn't able to do what I wanted either.

EDIT : 
I solve one of my problems :[image]
Now "Winner" will be displayed after "Stats" and "Perf", but it's fine.
But in large screen I still don't know how to make "Winner" the same size as the other col. After some research I read that it's not possible with Bootstrap 3, some can confirm ?

New code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-push-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>Results</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
                <h2>Stats</h2>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
                <h2>Perf</h2>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-lg-pull-8">
        <h2>Winner</h2>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to bootstrap 4 solved my problem, the height adjustment of all cols inside a row automatically taken into account.

Here is the final code

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-8 d-flex">
    <div class="row flex-1">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>RESULTS</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <h1>Stats</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <h1>Perf</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-4 order-first">
</div>
```

flex-1 is a class I made which contains only that : flex: 1 1 auto;